# Shaky text when using transform scale

Tags: css

I am trying to scale the size of a button on hover, but when this is done, the text looks shaky. I looked at some other posts and tried some of the suggestions, such as using `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;`, `transform: translateZ(0);` and `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`, but none seemed to work.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ad7n17so/

(I am using Firefox, if that makes a difference)

```
.button {
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the padding in em to pixels or percent?

Comment: @SravanS Yes, I just updated a fiddle using px and still encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backface-visibility: hidden;` let the situation better, but the text rendering remains weird (crispy at Firefox, Blurry on Chrome). This problem becomes smaller (mainly on Chrome) removing the padding and using a bigger line-height instead:

```css
.button {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.8em;  
}

.button:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
   -o-transform: scale(1.25);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
   transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Test Button</div>
```

Comment: I have added your suggestion to the fiddle, but the results have not changed: https://jsfiddle.net/ad7n17so/8/

Answer (score 7):

Just an FYI for people with shaky/jittery images with `transform: scale(1.05)` on :hover on Firefox, this fixed my problem.

```
transform: scale(1.05) rotate(0.02deg);
```

So it's totally a fake rotate Firefox hack that stops this glitchy image scale effect.

Comment: This did the trick. The accepted solution did not entirely fix the issue, child elements were still shaky.

Comment: Five years later – this fixes jittery transition even in Chrome !

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this same thing while resizing page to test responsiveness. The text goes all blurry, as well as some images. As far as i know, there is no way to fix this as the font is adjusting. Instead of animating every pixel of the font size, it tweens the animation. Because of that, it does not look clear every second of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

one quick solution that I got was, instead of directly applying transformation/transition or whatever styling you are applying, it would render much better if you wrap it up in other component (suppose inside a div) and apply the styling there, it would render much better and over the top if you add

`backface-visibility: hidden`

to the wrapper component, it gets even better !