# Shaky when using CSS transform on link

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a footer navigation. Navigation is an unordered list having six list items with each item having a anchor or link tag.

Now my question is that when i hover upon the list item which is basically a link it (translates -3px in Y axis --> according to the CSS code) but when it comes back to link or normal state the link text moves up and down.

What is causing this abnormal behavior?

My experience is fresh with CSS and HTML.

I have read somewhere about (backface visibility: hidden;) but don't know how to use it and where to use it can somehow resolve this issue but as i told earlier i am starting with CSS so bit confused how it works.

[image]

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4rem;
  background-color: #101d2c;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__link:link,
.nav__link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav__link:active,
.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: rgba(#fff, .05);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Find your dream home</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Request proposal</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Download home planner</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact us</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Submit your property</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Come work with us!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle/pen with your code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/aw33598/pen/PVLwzb?editors=1100#0

Comment: @Bodrov I have just found that my text has a shaky effect in mozilla not chrome. In chrome it works fine

Comment: I opened the pen in Firefox and it looks fine to me. Are you still getting the error in your browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518030/shaky-text-when-using-transform-scale

Comment: This is an issue with CSS transform. As a workaround, you could use a negative top margin to make the next move up on hover.

Comment: @braed thanks for your participation i have put margin-top: -3px; it somewhat reduces that shaky effect but not completely gone

Comment: @Bodrov yes i'm still getting this error in my mozilla i have also now updated my question with a visual representation of the problem please do see it for a better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain to you why CSS tranform isn't smooth but it's a common issue that i find myself noticing all over the web on a daily basis. CSS has many weird bugs and flaws and this is currently one of them.

Here's a workaround for your issue so that you can at least achieve what you want without the shaky text:

**Remove css transform and add negative top margin:**

```css
.nav__link:active,
.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: rgba(#fff, .05);
  transform: translateY(-3px); <-- remove this line
  margin-top: -6px; <-- add this line
}
```

I used 6px of negative top margin (`-6px`) because that looks very similar to using `3px` of css transform translate.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZweLp?editors=1100#0

Comment: Well the text shaky effect has reduced very much but not completely gone and for now this solution can be accepted. Thank You ! for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I have that problem, I use `backface-visibility: hidden;` and it usually fixes the problem.

Comment: I just tried using this in Firefox and saw no improvement :/

Comment: @braed yes no improvement

Comment: Firefox has some weird behavior when it comes to CSS transformations. Backface usually fixes them, while Chrome doesn't need them (I'm using Chrome and I see your menu working perfectly).

Comment: actually it works perfectly fine in my chrome too but the real culprit here is mozilla

Comment: I also see the menu working perfectly in Chrome but with shaky text in Firefox. Not using `transform` (e.g. using negative margin) fixes the shaky text for me.